# How to disable Camera Zoom on iPhone (xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera

I'm currently building an app that uses the iPhone camera. This may be an odd question but any idea how to disable the ability to zoom?

I've searched the internet high and low and so far I have come up with nothing. Any developers that may have some ideas, I'd love to hear from you!

Comment: i'm just curious: why do you want to prevent the user from zooming ?

Comment: @JeanLuc, I can't go into great detail but it's because the item being photographed is very specific and zooming a) would be of no advantage and b) would be inconvenient to the recipient of the photo.

Answer (score 2):

A guess would be to intercept all incoming touhces, by putting in a transoarent view in from of the camera view, and then handle touches of the shutter button manually. I don't think that this is part of the public API anyway.

Hope this helps,

Jonathan

Comment: I've managed to overlay a transparent image over the camera, but this seems such a messy solution. A transparent view is a good idea too, thank you @jonathanlking for your ideas, even if it's still a bit messy too. I wonder why Apple don't allow developers access to these controls :(

Comment: It doesn't have to be messy if you write your own class that inherits from UIView, and contains both the camera feed view and the transparent view as subviews. That way you would leave all the 'messy' stuff in that class, and leave your main code roughly unchanged to how it would be before.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the camera's overlay view will disable the pinch to zoom. This way is better than intercepting all touches because it does not disable the tap to change focus gesture.

```
UIView *cameraOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
cameraOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRec = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doPinch)];
[cameraOverlay addGestureRecognizer:pinchRec];
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay;
```